# Is it possible to make a small white Pop up appear on a click on a button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, leaflet, window

On this website: https://www.infrastructure.aws/
When you click on Availability Zones for exemple, it will show a small window, filled with text on the right of the page.
I would like to know if it's possible to have sometething similar on a leaflet map without javascript ?
This action will be run when a user will click on a certain button on my map!

Thank you very much for your help, and sorry for my english, i'm not native :(

Comment: Well, a [leaflet](https://leafletjs.com/) *is* a JavaScript library therefore you cannot have leflet without JavaScript, in the first place. For what concerns the "pop-in" window, from a quick look at the documentation, I think you could use the [layers feature](https://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control/) and customize the styling. Anyway you cannot have client-side interaction without JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Without JavaScript, i don't think there is a normal way.

Try to change the CSS of the "popup" from `display: none;` to `display: block;` by clicking the button.